# Dynatree checkboxes are not checked anymore

Tags: dynatree

I am finding that the Dynatree checkboxes are images and not real checkboxes.  However, I am assuming that the checkbox state when captured properly will be rendered through Javascript properly, and the correct image (partial checked, unchecked or completely checked) will show up.

I am using Dynatree and the correct JSON with all attributes being captured properly. During the time of testing, everything seems to be working fine as expected with correct nodes showing the proper checkbox state. 
However, I came back after the weekend and I tried to access the site utilizing the Dynatree;  and the checkboxes have disappeared completely.

```
"select": true,
"hideCheckbox": false,
"unselectable": false,
```

Anyone using Dynatree with checkboxes facing the same problem and how they resolved the issue.

Please help. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It's not the images...You can refer to the following link I am sure it will help and solve your issue :)

http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html

Comment: link only answers are discouraged. links go stale. Post the relevant information directly.

Comment: I have already checked out the document.  Bring up browser debugging tools (any), and if you hover over the checkbox, you will see that it is style based. But still I am assuming that the issue of showing whether it is checked; partial or uncheck - is resolvable. However in my case, even though it seems to work and capture the true state - somehow, when I brought up the site after the weekend; it failed to capture the true state and showed all of checkbox unchecked. Thx